# JS \ CSS - images just popout or popin without animation

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create fade in\out effects using JS\CSS playing with `opacity` property. Images just pop in or pop out without the desired effect. Can't figure out what am I doing wrong.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbfg70hu/2/).
JS:

```
document.getElementById("in").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000054045268-j4bv9x-large.jpg";
  img.setAttribute("id", "dt");
  document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(img);
  img.className = "fadein";
  console.log("sould fade in");
});

document.getElementById("out").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("sould fade out");
  var img = document.getElementById("dt");
  img.className = "fadeout";
  console.log(img);
  img.remove();
});
```

CSS:

```
#frame img {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s;
  /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: opacity 2s;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  width: 350px;
  margin: auto;
}

.fadein {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: all 1s ease !important;
}

.fadeout {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="frame"></div>

<button id="in">fade in</button>
<button id="out">fade out</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById("in").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000054045268-j4bv9x-large.jpg";
  img.setAttribute("id", "dt");
  document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(img);
  img.className = "fadein";
  console.log("sould fade in");
});


document.getElementById("out").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("sould fade out");
  var img = document.getElementById("dt");
  img.className = "fadeout";
  console.log(img);
  img.remove();
});
```

```css
#frame img {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s;
  /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: opacity 2s;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  width: 350px;
  margin: auto;
}

.fadein {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

.fadeout {
  opacity: 0 !important;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame"></div>

<button id="in">fade in</button>
<button id="out">fade out</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

When a new element is appended to the DOM, the browsers layout engine is busy computing dimensions and painting the element onto the view context. There must be a slight delay before assigning transitions to the element. So, if you wrap the CSS class assignment inside a `setTimeout`, you'll be fine. Like this:

```
document.getElementById("in").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000054045268-j4bv9x-large.jpg";
    img.setAttribute("id", "dt");
    document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(img);
    setTimeout(() => img.className = "fadein", 100);
});
```

You might need to tweak the timeout value in the range [0, 100] depending on browser and horsepower of your host machine.

I see that you assign `transition-property` to `all` in your CSS. Please know that this is expensive as it forces the browser to optimize for possible transitions on all CSS properties on elements with the `.fadeIn` or `.fadeOut` CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

Place the create Element of `img` globel

```js
var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000054045268-j4bv9x-large.jpg";
  img.setAttribute("id", "dt");
  document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(img);
  
document.getElementById("in").addEventListener("click", function() {
   img.className = "fadein";
  console.log("sould fade in");
});

document.getElementById("out").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("sould fade out");
 
  img.className = "fadeout";
 
  
  console.log(img);
  
});
```

```css
#frame img {
  
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s;
  /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: opacity 2s;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  width: 350px;
  height:0;
  margin: auto;
}

.fadein {
 height:auto !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: all 1s ease !important;
}

.fadeout {
 
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame"></div>

<button id="in">fade in</button>
<button id="out">fade out</button>
```